# How to nest Stack Navigator inside a Drawer Navigator with navigation v5+

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

my project structure is something like:

- app.js (Loads data and a drawer navigator)
- MainScreen (Load cards using the data fetched before in a preview mode and when you click you have a NewsComponent that fetch the complete data for that record)
- NewsScreen (Load a full article using the data fetched before)

in my App.js I'm using a drawer navigator like that:

```
return (
      <NavigationContainer>
        <Drawer.Navigator initialRouteName="Main">
          <Drawer.Screen name="Main" options={{ headerShown: false}}>
            {props => <MainScreen {...props} extraData={App.news} />}
          </Drawer.Screen>
          <Drawer.Screen name="Court Reservation" component={CourtReservation}></Drawer.Screen>
          <Drawer.Screen name="News" component={NewsScreen}></Drawer.Screen>
        </Drawer.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
    );
  }
```

but I need to insert an stack navigator inside the Main component in order to show the records (NewsScreen) because if not when I go back to the list (Main) and again to a different record the content is not updating and the first record is being shown.

I tried several times but I'm getting all sort of errors. Right now my MainScreen goes like this:

```
render() {
    return (
      <Container>
        <Header>
          <Left>
            <Button onPress={() => this.props.navigation.openDrawer()} transparent>
              <Icon name='menu' />
            </Button>
          </Left>
          <Body>
            <Title>Header</Title>
          </Body>
          <Right />
        </Header>
        <FlatList
          data={this.state.news}
          onEndReached={this.fetchMoreNews}
          onEndReachedThreshold={0.5}
          keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
          renderItem={({item}) => (
            <Content>
          <CardNewsComponent data={item} nav={this.props.navigation}/>
          </Content>
          )}/>
        </Container>
    );
  }
```

But is using the drawer navigation ir order to "Navigate" to the component.

How can I integrate a stack navigator to do so?

---

EDIT:

After the kind awnser my app.js is like:

```
    import * as React from 'react';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createDrawerNavigator } from '@react-navigation/drawer';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import MainScreen from './screens/MainScreen';
import NewsScreen from './screens/NewsScreen';
import CourtReservation from './screens/CourtReservation';
import * as SplashScreen from 'expo-splash-screen';
import * as Font from 'expo-font';
import { Ionicons } from '@expo/vector-icons';
import axios from 'axios';


const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();
const Stack = createStackNavigator();

const myStack = (<Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Main">
              <Stack.Screen name="Main" options={{ headerShown: false}}>
                {props => <MainScreen {...props} extraData={App.news} />}
              </Stack.Screen>
              <Stack.Screen name="News" component={NewsScreen}></Stack.Screen>
            </Stack.Navigator>)
       

export default class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    appIsReady: false,
  };

  news = {};

  async componentDidMount() {
    // Prevent native splash screen from autohiding
    try {
      await SplashScreen.preventAutoHideAsync();
    } catch (e) {
      console.warn(e);
    }
    this.prepareResources();
  }

  /**
   * Method that serves to load resources and make API calls
   */
  prepareResources = async () => {
    await performAPICalls();
    await downloadAssets();

    this.setState({ appIsReady: true }, async () => {
      await SplashScreen.hideAsync();
    });
  };

  render() {
    if (!this.state.appIsReady) {
      return null;
    }

    return (
      <NavigationContainer>
        <Drawer.Navigator initialRouteName="Main">
          <Drawer.Screen name="Main" component={myStack}></Drawer.Screen>
          <Drawer.Screen name="Court Reservation" component={CourtReservation}></Drawer.Screen>
        </Drawer.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
    );
  }
}

// Put any code you need to prepare your app in these functions
async function performAPICalls() {
  await axios.get('https://alqueriadelbasket.com/?r=noticias/FetchNoticiasJson&boundBot=0&boundTop=5')
    .then((response) => {
      App.news = response.data;
    }).catch((error)=> {
      console.log(error);
    })
}
async function downloadAssets() {
    await Font.loadAsync({
      Roboto: require('native-base/Fonts/Roboto.ttf'),
      Roboto_medium: require('native-base/Fonts/Roboto_medium.ttf'),
      ...Ionicons.font,
  });
}
```

And my main Screen

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Container, Content, Header, Left, Button, Icon, Right, Body, Title} from 'native-base';
import {FlatList} from 'react-native';
import CardNewsComponent from './components/CardNewsComponent';
import axios from 'axios';

export default class MainScreen extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      news: this.props.extraData,
      boundBot: 6,
      bountTop: 11,
      error: null,
    };
  }

  fetchMoreNews = () => {
    axios.get(`https://alqueriadelbasket.com/?r=noticias/FetchNoticiasJson&boundBot=${this.state.boundBot}&boundTop=${this.state.bountTop}`)
    .then((response) => {
      this.setState({
        boundBot: this.state.boundBot+5,
        boundTop: this.state.boundTop+5,
        news: this.state.news.concat(response.data)
      })
    }).catch((error)=> {
      console.log(error);
    })
  }

  newsData = this.props.extraData;
  render() {
    return (
      <Container>
        <Header>
          <Left>
            <Button onPress={() => this.props.navigation.openDrawer()} transparent>
              <Icon name='menu' />
            </Button>
          </Left>
          <Body>
            <Title>Header</Title>
          </Body>
          <Right />
        </Header>
        <FlatList
          data={this.state.news}
          onEndReached={this.fetchMoreNews}
          onEndReachedThreshold={0.5}
          keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
          renderItem={({item}) => (
            <Content>
          <CardNewsComponent data={item} nav={this.props.navigation}/>
          </Content>
          )}/>
        </Container>
    );
  }
}
```

The error is "Got an invalid value for 'component' prop for the screen Main, It must be a valid react component.

Funny thing that Main was working like a charm before... :/

---

EDIT2:

After try and look inside of the official doc.

This was the problem:

It can't be a const, it have to be a function... So I'll added the function to the drawer nav and it worked like a charm.

here's the code:

```
function MyStack() {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Main">
              <Stack.Screen name="Main" options={{ headerShown: false}}>
                {props => <MainScreen {...props} extraData={App.news} />}
              </Stack.Screen>
              <Stack.Screen name="News" component={NewsScreen}></Stack.Screen>
            </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}
```

Comment: just a shot in the dark, can you rename `myStack` to `MyStack`? it is a possible reason

Comment: Still not working, same error, renamed in both Const... and DrawerNav component={...} any other guess?

Comment: I just find the solution I'll put in the main question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Inside the drawer navigator, we have drawer screens

```js
  <Drawer.Navigator initialRouteName="Main">
     <Drawer.Screen name="Main" options={{ headerShown: false}}>
     ......
     //you can add a Stack Navigator as a screen here

  </Drawer.Navigator>
```

So you can define a Stack navigator above as such:

```js
  const MyStack = <Stack.Navigator>
                  //your stack screens     
                  ......
                 </Stack.Navigator>
```

Then, use it as a drawer screen:

```js
<Drawer.Screen name="main" component={MyStack} />
```

Comment: With the edit I'm having "Undefined is not an object (Evaluating "Stack.Navigator" any guess?

Comment: I think you missed the import statement : `import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';`

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I thought I have edited again, the error is: "Got an invalid value for 'component' prop for the screen Main, It must be a valid react component. (Check main awnser again and thanks)